# Name referencing for arbitrary text?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems

In my TeX file I have a something like this:

```
\newcommand{\head}[2]{
\textbf{#1 \imp:} \textit{#2}\\
}

\newcommand{\definition}[1]{
\head{Definition}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\lemma}[1]{
\head{Lemma}{#1}
}
```

As I write my lemmata and definitions it is hard to keep track of them. So I'd like to use labels. And then I'd love to write something like this

```
According to Lemma 3 we know that ....
```

Where Lemma 3 is filled in on the fly by `nameref`, so that I'd only have to write this

```
According to \nameref{lemma_cook} we know that .....
```

I tried to use labels and references but they only work within sections, figures and stuff that can be enumerated. Is there a way to adjust my new commands to make this possible (put them in an enumerable environment, use a virtual counter, use `hyperref` package, ...)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem not to have heard about `\newtheorem`.

Comment: You're right. Never heard of that, but exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing things by hand, use the `\newtheorem` command; the `amsthm` package extends the command with the notion of “current style”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%\theoremstyle{plain} % implicit
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] % theorems are numbered by section
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}       % lemmas share the numbering

\theoremstyle{definition} % body font is upright
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definitions share the numbering

\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark} % unnumbered

\begin{document}

\section{Basics}

\begin{lem}\label{lem:easy}
$1+1=2$.
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:add}
$1+1+1=3$.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
The proof is easy when one recalls Lemma~\ref{lem:easy}.
\end{proof}

\begin{defn}
A natural number is \emph{nice} when it has good properties.
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:main}
Every natural number is nice.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
Easy induction, the inductive step is provided by Theorem~\ref{thm:add}.
\end{proof}

\begin{rem}
All of the above extends to real numbers, but this paper is too
short for showing the proof.
\end{rem}

\end{document}
```

[image]