# Refer to arbitrary text (without numbering and not by section)

Tags: cross-referencing

So we can refer to *sections* with *counter* via `\label{…}` and `\ref{…}`.

We can refer to *sections* with *custom* *text* via package `hyperref` like so:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70153

We can refer to *arbitrary* *text* with *counter* like so:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4024
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179008
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3914144
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150061

But how can we refer to *arbitrary* *text* with *custom* *text* ? I.e. refer to an arbitrary location in the document with our custom text.

For example, let's say I want to refer to the previous paragraph using the word "previous" (no counters).

Can this be done? (I'm new to LaTeX).
Thanks.

I've also read the [Sharelatex's documentation on cross-referencing](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Cross_referencing_sections_and_equations) but did not find an answer.

Comment: you can use hyperref's hypertarget and hyperlink markup (this is unrelated to sharelatex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you give me a link to start with?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok I found it [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Hyperlinks). Shall I delete this question?

Comment: nah I've answered now:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

one two three

\phantomsection\label{zzz}four five six

\clearpage

see \hyperref[zzz]{previous} paragraph on a different page so the link jump is clearer.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the answer. Can you tell me what is \phantomsection additionally here?

Comment: it leaves the invisible anchor at that point, like a section heading would so the `\label` and `\hyperref` can make a link back  (the older `\hypertarget` would also set a target but only at the pag elevel, see texdoc hyperref,  section 4 @thanopi57